# Getting Content of PHP file upload error

Tags: php, file-upload, error-handling, php-5.3

I am working with the move_uploaded_file() function in PHP.  I've managed to successfully troubleshoot a problem I was encountering, but I would like to be able to get the actual content of the warnning or error message.  According to php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) the move_uploaded_file() function returns FALSE and a warning on failure.  I want the actual content of the warning, such as "failed to open stream: Permission denied..." so that I can record which errors are occurring.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do using this: $_FILES['userfile']['error']

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php